# Failed to reboot after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: grub2, upgrade

Since 22.04 was released yesterday I decided to upgrade my development machine, a 10 year old hp Pavilion with AMD processor. The upgrade went OK and completed in 1.5 hours but failed to reboot and went into emergency mode. I ran boot repair and the output was put in the following paste buffer:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5bm8bNgY6y/

I have plenty of disk space. / is only 72% full.

Other than a complete install, which would cause as many problems as it would solve as I have over a dozen apps I would need to reinstall, I am at a loss as to what to do.

I have a dual boot system, with Windows 10 in another partition. Ubuntu is the primary OS.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

@heynnema

fstab:

```
cat /mnt/etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=B444-715A  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
#/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/bigswapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
#
#
#UUID=1C1679C61679A186 /media/kevin/Windows ntfs errors=remount -ro 0 1
#
# Ubuntu on 2 tB drive /dev/sdb8
UUID=758626aa-c2cf-4faf-a16d-79370c7d3bcb /               ext4    -ro 0       1
# Windows partition on internal HDD
UUID=21BFBE168406B05D /media/kevin/Windows ntfs -ro 0 1
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=7425e72e-1e3e-754b-e1c1-724f00d33c98 /Ubuntu_sec ext4 -ro 0 1
#/dev/sdb3 /media/kevin/Ubuntu_data   ext4  errors=remount -ro 0 1
#/dev/sdc3 /media/kevin/Windows7 ntfs errors=remount -ro 0 1
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

blkid:

```
sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="B444-715A" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="5fb77005-5d5f-4574-a190-f0717fd137aa"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Windows" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="21BFBE168406B05D" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="WIndows_primary" PARTUUID="6e7c930c-32b3-4145-9459-33b90c964d62"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Windows RE tools" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="BE12F7A512F760B7" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="450b37ce-7747-4712-9927-69d6bb53b976"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="RECOVERY" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="860E51920E517BDD" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="c789d063-9ad4-423d-9354-4f3c70558dd0"
/dev/sda6: UUID="758626aa-c2cf-4faf-a16d-79370c7d3bcb" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Ubuntu" PARTUUID="35691675-f076-4e2f-a12d-9c2e25dd6999"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="SYSTEM" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="F49C1AE3CB6928FA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="47ba187e-01"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Windows10_new" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="3E1562AEE8601345" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="47ba187e-02"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="ba8b676d-604c-7712-c178-2fe538ff9545" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="47ba187e-05"
/dev/sdb7: UUID="214e9383-fa91-4dc8-86f8-2c46725011f8" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="47ba187e-07"
/dev/sdb8: LABEL="Ubuntu primary" UUID="7425e72e-1e3e-754b-e1c1-724f00d33c98" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="47ba187e-08"
/dev/sdg1: UUID="45990508-f44c-4bf4-a315-b41e0cdb5c67" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c5adefda-01"
/dev/sdb6: UUID="e8e98bcc-c555-1bd7-0ef7-0733b525314c" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="47ba187e-06"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="57cf924b-89f1-4bd3-97a8-dadd789b4762"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
```

swap: (no output)

```
swapon -s
```

memory:

```
free -h
      Total.      Used.    Free.    Shared.    Buff/cache.   Available
Mem:  15Gi.    144Mi.   14Gi.    9.0 Mi.     285Mi.        14Gi
Swap:   0B.     0B.        0B
```

@heynnema
I repaired fstab by commenting out the swap lines and changed the lines with -ro to "defaults=rw". The system now boots into 21.10 but does not want to upgrade to 22.04. It says no new releases available.

Thanks for your help.

I got the upgrade to start using:
do-release-upgrade **-d**
@heynnema
Well the upgrade proceeded to the point where it said reboot at my convenience, which I did. However the system freezes on reboot. I have a screen shot, and decyphering it is above my pay grade. Now it says kernel panic:
VFS: Cannot open root device "sda6" or unknown -block (0,0): error-6.
The 21.10 upgrade seemed normal. Why did the upgrade to 22.04 fail?
I have a screenshot, which is a .HEIC image, but cannot attach.

Output from ls -al /boot, from previous kernel, which is 22.04:

```
ls -al /boot
total 222164
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Apr 23 18:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root     4096 Apr 22 14:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   257253 Mar 29 10:09 config-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   260489 Mar 30 11:28 config-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   237975 Apr  8 04:44 config-5.4.0-109-generic
drwx------  5 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Apr 23 18:57 grub
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Apr 22 15:28 grub.bak
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Apr 22 15:01 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 97563363 Apr 23 18:58 initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 76596883 Apr 23 18:58 initrd.img-5.4.0-109-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Apr 22 15:01 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-109-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182800 Feb  6 15:35 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184476 Feb  6 15:35 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184980 Feb  6 15:35 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  5976259 Mar 29 10:09 System.map-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  6246119 Mar 30 11:28 System.map-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4759493 Apr  8 04:44 System.map-5.4.0-109-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Apr 22 15:01 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 10246688 Mar 29 10:13 vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 11073600 Mar 30 11:29 vmlinuz-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 13668608 Apr  8 04:45 vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Apr 22 15:01 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-generic
```

lsb_release -r
Release:    22.04

Perhaps I should edit grub and move this line upwards.
This was kernel 5.15.0.25

Latest@ 9:45 pm EDT:

```
ls -al /boot
total 324984
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root      4096 Apr 23 20:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root      4096 Apr 22 14:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    257253 Mar 29 10:09 config-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    260489 Mar 30 11:28 config-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    237975 Apr  8 04:44 config-5.4.0-109-generic
drwx------  5 root root      4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root      4096 Apr 23 18:57 grub
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root      4096 Apr 22 15:28 grub.bak
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        28 Apr 23 20:25 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  97563363 Apr 23 18:58 initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 105285205 Apr 23 20:20 initrd.img-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  76596883 Apr 23 18:58 initrd.img-5.4.0-109-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        28 Apr 22 15:01 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-109-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    182800 Feb  6 15:35 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    184476 Feb  6 15:35 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    184980 Feb  6 15:35 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root   5976259 Mar 29 10:09 System.map-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root   6246119 Mar 30 11:28 System.map-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-------  1 root root   4759493 Apr  8 04:44 System.map-5.4.0-109-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 Apr 22 15:01 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  10246688 Mar 29 10:13 vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  11073600 Mar 30 11:29 vmlinuz-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  13668608 Apr  8 04:45 vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 Apr 22 15:01 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-generic
```

June 27 2022:
The problem has bitten again when upgrading my primary computer from 20.04 to 21.04, the first step in the process of upgrading to 22.04 LTS. This time I can't even get into emergency mode. I just get a grub prompt. I think I saw a panic message during the upgrade and something to the effect that /dev/sda4, the primary Ubuntu partition, is corrupted. I can begin to list the contents of /etc/fstab and the output of lsblk, plus the other things you asked last time for me to do.
I ran boot repair twice but that didn't fix the boot problem. Here is the Boot Info  for the two iterations:
paste.ubuntu.com/p/JQfwPJkZvJ
paste.ubuntu.com/p/gWPD9GrTZp
I will try to study them but I really don't know enough to make complete sense of them. Thanks for your help in advance. Last time you said to edit the question but I can't see that option available now.

I just tried to fix /dev/sda4 as follows:
sudo grub-install /dev/sda4 --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/boot/efi'. ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda4  Installing for i386-pc platform. grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of` /cow'.
sudo fdisk -l:
Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EZAZ-00G
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 269D15EA-10B9-4A5E-9C29-75C578F72C80

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048      34815      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2      104448    1128447    1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1128448  977690947  976562500 465.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4   977692672 1954252799  976560128 465.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  1954252800 3797503999 1843251200 878.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  3797504000 3899903999  102400000  48.8G Linux swap

sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

I will now try to see if I can boot into recovery mode.
It won't get to the grub menu, just the grub prompt, so I determined the root device and set it with root=(hd3,4), then linux=/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.52 and initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.13.52 and then "boot", but it said, after a while "root filesystem not specified" and hangs in initramfs.
I repeated the latter but added "root=/dev/sda4 ro" in the linux command. This time it booted, but into emergency mode.

I had a look at the journalctl -xb log and it seemed there were errors on sdc disk ( my external backup) but no errors I noticed on sda.

Comment: What was the error message that you got when it booted to emergency mode? What is the prompt that you see... a # or initramfs? Do you have a Ubuntu Live USB flash key available? Does Windows still boot? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Windows does boot and I can boot into a number of older installations available from grub. If I hit ESC while booting I see messages like cannot create swap and also some errors in my fstab.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/fstab` and `blkid` and `free -h` and `swapon -s`. Remember to start comments to me with @heynnema.

Comment: Will do that tomorrow. The 20.04 system  worked fine before the upgrade.

Comment: @heynnema.-  There was no output from swapon -s

Comment: free -h
      Total.      Used.    Free.    Shared.    Buff/cache.   Available
Mem:  15Gi.    144Mi.   14Gi.    9.0 Mi.     285Mi.        14Gi
Swap:   0B.     0B.        0B  There is too much to copy manually from the screen for fstab and blkid. I will attempt to fix fstab with a Live CD

Comment: Your swap is broken. I'll need to see /etc/fstab and blkid to give you fixes.

Comment: You have 3 swap lines in /etc/fstab. The first one, which is commented out, is the correct one, but needs tabs removed. The other two should be deleted. Reboot. Then do `free -h` and `swapon -s` to confirm that swap is working again.

Comment: @heynnema please see edited question for further results.This has now progressed to a frozen 22.04 installation after upgrade.

Comment: Boot to either Recovery Mode, or a previous kernel, via the GRUB menu, and show me `ls -al /boot`.

Comment: @heynnema Added output from ls -al /boot

Comment: You're missing your ramdisk for kernel 5.15.0-25-generic, and the initrd.img symlink is wrong. Try `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.15.0-25-generic` and redo the symlink.

Comment: @heynnema What do you mean redo the symlink and how could this happen with a standard upgrade?

Comment: @heynnema OK, I got it. I will try to reboot hands free and see.

Comment: @heynnema Nope, does not work. I have to use 5.13.0-40, which is also Jellyfish.

Comment: Back from dinner. Sorry. Show me the current status of `ls -al /boot`.

Comment: @heynnema Hope dinner was good, no heartburn. See above for latest ls -al /boot. As I said, kernel 5.13.0-40 boots OK, and is Jammy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135766/discussion-between-heynnema-and-user78290).

Comment: @heynnema The problem has bitten again when upgrading my primary computer from 20.04 to 21.04, the first step in the process of upgrading to 22.04 LTS. This time I can't even get into emergency mode. I just get a grub prompt. I think I saw a panic message during the upgrade and something to the effect that /dev/sda4, the primary Ubuntu partition, is corrupted. I can begin to list the contents of /etc/fstab and the output of lsblk, plus the other things you asked last time for me to do.

Comment: I ran boot repair twice but that didn't fix the boot problem. Here is the Boot Info from the I ran boot repair and here is the Boot Info output for the two iterations: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JQfwPJkZvJ/
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gWPD9GrTZp/
I will try to study them but I really don't know enough to make complete sense of them. Thanks for your help in advance. Last time you said to edit the question but I can't see that option available now.

Comment: How big is the disk? Is your computer new enough to use UEFI? Boot to a Ubuntu Live USB and in terminal, show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard, so we can check if the BIOS is up to date.

Comment: Your disk is getting I/O errors. I see stuff about sdb1 having invalid characters or spaces. I see stuff about WUBI installs (WUBI has been not been valid for years). I see multiple versions of Ubuntu and Windows. All in all, it looks like a mess... sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User did an upgrade from 20.04 to 21.10 to 22.04, and although all upgrades indicated successful completion, it wouldn't boot into 22.04, although prior kernels booted fine.

As you can see from the following `ls -al /boot` output, the 22.04 upgrade failed to create the ramdisk file **initrd.img-5.15.0-25-generic**, and failed to update the symlink for **initrd.img**.

ls -al /boot

```
total 222164
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Apr 23 18:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root     4096 Apr 22 14:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   257253 Mar 29 10:09 config-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   260489 Mar 30 11:28 config-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   237975 Apr  8 04:44 config-5.4.0-109-generic
drwx------  5 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Apr 23 18:57 grub
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Apr 22 15:28 grub.bak
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Apr 22 15:01 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 97563363 Apr 23 18:58 initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 76596883 Apr 23 18:58 initrd.img-5.4.0-109-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Apr 22 15:01 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-109-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182800 Feb  6 15:35 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184476 Feb  6 15:35 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184980 Feb  6 15:35 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  5976259 Mar 29 10:09 System.map-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  6246119 Mar 30 11:28 System.map-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4759493 Apr  8 04:44 System.map-5.4.0-109-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Apr 22 15:01 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 10246688 Mar 29 10:13 vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 11073600 Mar 30 11:29 vmlinuz-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 13668608 Apr  8 04:45 vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Apr 22 15:01 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-generic
```

Here, we manually created the ramdisk file, updated the symlink, and updated GRUB with:

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.15.0-25-generic

cd /boot

sudo ln -s initrd.img-5.15.0-25-generic initrd.img

sudo update-grub

reboot
```

You can see the changes in the following `ls -al /boot` output:

ls -al /boot

```
total 324984
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root      4096 Apr 23 20:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root      4096 Apr 22 14:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    257253 Mar 29 10:09 config-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    260489 Mar 30 11:28 config-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    237975 Apr  8 04:44 config-5.4.0-109-generic
drwx------  5 root root      4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root      4096 Apr 23 18:57 grub
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root      4096 Apr 22 15:28 grub.bak
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        28 Apr 23 20:25 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  97563363 Apr 23 18:58 initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 105285205 Apr 23 20:20 initrd.img-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  76596883 Apr 23 18:58 initrd.img-5.4.0-109-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        28 Apr 22 15:01 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-109-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    182800 Feb  6 15:35 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    184476 Feb  6 15:35 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    184980 Feb  6 15:35 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root   5976259 Mar 29 10:09 System.map-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root   6246119 Mar 30 11:28 System.map-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-------  1 root root   4759493 Apr  8 04:44 System.map-5.4.0-109-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 Apr 22 15:01 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  10246688 Mar 29 10:13 vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  11073600 Mar 30 11:29 vmlinuz-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  13668608 Apr  8 04:45 vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        25 Apr 22 15:01 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-generic
```

We also edited /etc/fstab to correct issues with the /swapfile.

Ubuntu 22.04 is now booting properly.

Comment: I am extremely grateful for this expert assistance. Kudos to heynnema!

Comment: @user78290 Remember to verify your swap with `free -h` and `swapon -s`.

Comment: 2.0 Gb swap is showing.

Comment: @user78290 perfect!

Comment: @user78290 Keep an eye on swap usage. If it approaches 2G , the system may freeze, and I'll have to give you instructions on how to increase the /swapfile.

Comment: As I said, this is the development system and I don't have all apps running as I do on my primary system, so swap is maybe superfluous. Right now zero swap is in use.

Comment: @user78290 Once you bring up Firefox/Chrome, and any development tools like VCode/etc., you'll see that swap usage increase.

Comment: Firefox is running, with about 10 tabs. I do not like Chrome. There are memory leaks and I get Netgear popups I can't kill.

Comment: @user78290 re: popups... delete all of the netgear cookies in Chrome.