# Failed to reboot after upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04

Tags: boot, grub2

I have experienced a similar, but not quite the same problem as this question:

**Failed to reboot after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04**

while upgrading from 20.04 to 21.04 yesterday, as the first step before going to 22.04. I ran a perfectly normal upgrade but grub seem to be corrupted and boot repair was unable to fix the problem in 3 iterations. I have pasted its output in the previous question.

I have also tried to boot from the grub menu but just precipitated an exit to emergency mode. At this point I'm stuck. I'm tempted to try a fresh install of 22.04 over the 20.04 installation but am afraid of losing my copious data and apps. I have edited the aforementioned question and added more information.

Here is some more data:

```
sudo df -k /mnt
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4      479566512 383311188  71824940  85% /mnt

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EZAZ-00G
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 269D15EA-10B9-4A5E-9C29-75C578F72C80

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048      34815      32768    16M Microsoft reserved

/dev/sda2      104448    1128447    1024000   500M EFI System

/dev/sda3     1128448  977690947  976562500 465.7G Microsoft basic data

/dev/sda4   977692672 1954252799  976560128 465.7G Linux filesystem

/dev/sda5  1954252800 3797503999 1843251200 878.9G Linux filesystem

/dev/sda6  3797504000 3899903999  102400000  48.8G Linux swap





Disk /dev/sdb: 1.82 TiB, 2000398933504 bytes, 3907029167 sectors
Disk model: Ultra Slim MT  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa0f8cd62

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            34816  921632767  921597952 439.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sdb2  *    1433632768 3319283711 1885650944 899.1G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sde: 931.51 GiB, 1000202043392 bytes, 1953519616 sectors
Disk model: Ext HDD 1021    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00261ddd

Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sde1               63  204796619 204796557  97.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

dev/sde2  *     204796620  723010251 518213632 247.1G 83 Linux

/dev/sde3        723011584 1235009535 511997952 244.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sde4       1235011582 1953517567 718505986 342.6G  5 Extended

/dev/sde5       1235011584 1644611583 409600000 195.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sde6       1644613632 1953517567 308903936 147.3G 83 Linux



ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

 cat /mnt/etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=1a961ca5-8682-433c-801d-8295ac7b88d8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=F0AB-BFAE  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=e419774b-3520-424d-82ce-5ebc320af6a9 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=3e565a6f-c534-4709-8a72-f387666832ee none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=1C1679C61679A186 /media/kevin/Seagate_Backup_Plus_Drive  ntfs auto,errors=remount-ro 0 1
#UUID=1C1679C61679A186 /media/kevin/Seagate\137Backup\137Plus\137Drive  ntfs errors=remount-ro 0 1
#UUID=3da2eec5-4d9c-442f-b90b-5192a1f3fe40 LABEL="Ubuntu data" /media/kevin/Ubuntu\040data   ext4  errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=3da2eec5-4d9c-442f-b90b-5192a1f3fe40  /media/kevin/Ubuntu\040data   ext4  auto,errors=remount-ro 0 1
#/dev/sdc3 /media/kevin/Windows7 ntfs errors=remount -ro 0 1
#/dev/sdc5 /media/kevin/Pictures_backup ntfs errors=remount -ro 0 1
UUID=16F40E1CF40DFEAD /media/kevin/Windows_ultra ntfs auto,errors=remount-ro 0 1
UUID=1783603b-08f2-4763-ab03-bd8e3bb65d6e  /media/kevin/Ubuntu_2nd_back  ext4 auto,errors=remount-rw 0 1    
UUID=32AC0BF47435BEA0 /media/kevin/Pictures_backup ntfs errors=remount-ro 0 1    

blkid /dev/sda4
/dev/sda4: UUID="1a961ca5-8682-433c-801d-8295ac7b88d8" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5b763976-d826-4894-9583-d611fa20c1fb"
```

Comment: [Ubuntu Upgrade tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) will **not** upgrade a system to an EOL release; and given [Ubuntu 21.04 has been EOL for some time](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/) you cannot *release-upgrade* to 21.04; so please clarify your question details.  Your system describes something which isn't possible if done using Ubuntu standard tools (it's **not** QA-tested or *supported*)

Comment: FYI:  I'm involved with QA-testing, and regularly *upgrade via re-install* of **desktop** systems, where the non-destruction of data, plus automatically re-install  of *manually installed* programs is tested for ! but you're devoid of *clear* specifics (desktop install? server install?) and describe a process that is missing details (*20.04 to 21.10 is currently supported/possible, not 20.04 to 21.04!*) so if things go wrong, a non-destructive install is very possible... but I'd always opt to use *supported* & QA-tested *release-upgrade* paths if you don't want problems.

Answer (score 0):

follow this question to get an idea how to resolve your problem
[Failed to reboot after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403869/failed-to-reboot-after-upgrade-from-20-04-to-22-04)

what shows you this command (try to access terminal in recovery mode or with live usb/dvd)

```
ls -al /boot
```

in future try to install a fresh install of ubuntu 22.04 not upgrade distro version.

with live usb/dvd copy your data and reinstall

Comment: I am doing a fresh install right now, after having made extra backups, in addition to the twice weekly incremental backups I run with rsync. ls -al /boot seems unremarkable to me. I cannot fathom why boot repair failed (3 times).

Comment: But, rather than installing 22.04 alongside 20.04 or Windows, I would like to reuse the partition where I installed 21.04, which is /. I have a separate /home on another partition. So I am going to try the "Something Else" option for now.

Comment: Well, the installation went well. I'm back in business. Some of the data, like Thunderbird, seems to be there. It remains to be seen whether all the apps I have to reinstall will work out of the box with my data. In future I'm not going to upgrade every LTS. I will wait until 2027 when support for 22.04 ends.