# Upgrade 20.04 LTS Desktop to 22.04 LTS Desktop - How to prevent a crash or to recover your previous kernel and OS?

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, crash, do-release-upgrade, recovery-mode

I tried to do release upgrade from 20.04 LTS Desktop to 22.04 LTS Desktop. During the installation progress everything seemed fine till the end. After restart the Grub boot loader seemed normally, but every choice I made did not load something succesсfully. Even my old kernels didn't load till the end.. to get a login screen..

Do you have any ideas, how can I recover my SSD with current or previous OS?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: you are silent on what research you have done but is this link helpful? https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-downgrade-ubuntu-linux-system-to-its-previous-version

Comment: Thank you very much for the article you shared to me! Unfortunatelly it did not help me.. :(
I will try to follow this tips and keep the status of my problem solving updated.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403869/failed-to-reboot-after-upgrade-from-20-04-to-22-04?rq=1