# Kernel panic - cannot boot after trying to upgrade from 20.4 to 22.04.1

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, kernel

I tried upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04.1 as the os suggested, after reboot I get

`Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`

I tried following this:
[Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0)

but it did not help, also it removed windows from my boot menu. (I am on dual boot, can still boot windows but only if i press F12 to get advanced boot menu and so on)

I am using a live usb (try ubuntu) because I cannot boot any kernel from the advanced boot menu. I tried from that link the thing with mounting the file system and running commands there, the commands seemed to work but ubuntu will still not boot.

I also tried following this:
[Failed to reboot after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403869/failed-to-reboot-after-upgrade-from-20-04-to-22-04)

but it didnt work either.

ls in the /boot directory shows this:

```
config-5.8.0-45-generic       initrd.img-5.8.0-45-generic
efi                           initrd.img.old
grub                          memtest86+.bin
grub.bak                      memtest86+.elf
initrd.img                    memtest86+_multiboot.bin
initrd.img-5.15.0-25-generic  System.map-5.8.0-45-generic
initrd.img-5.15.0-43.46       vmlinuz
initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic  vmlinuz-5.8.0-45-generic
initrd.img-5.4.0-56-generic   vmlinuz.old
```

and ls -al /boot shows

```
total 95148
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Sep 14 20:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root     4096 Mar  2  2021 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   248277 Feb 23  2021 config-5.8.0-45-generic
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root     4096 Aug 22  2020 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Sep 14 20:42 grub
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Sep 14 19:08 grub.bak
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Mar 22  2021 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.8.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8903818 Sep 14 20:53 initrd.img-5.15.0-25-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8897018 Sep 14 19:48 initrd.img-5.15.0-43.46
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8903977 Sep 14 20:37 initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8903934 Sep 14 20:12 initrd.img-5.4.0-56-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 45672417 Sep 14 20:41 initrd.img-5.8.0-45-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Mar 23  2021 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.8.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182800 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184476 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184980 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  5520433 Feb 23  2021 System.map-5.8.0-45-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Mar 22  2021 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-45-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  9781120 Feb 24  2021 vmlinuz-5.8.0-45-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Mar 23  2021 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-45-generic
```

but im guessing some of the things i've tried might have affected the output, im unsure.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: did you run the exact command from the other link? you should replace the kernel version with your own: `5.8.0-45-generic`

Comment: oh also, on a live usb, you need to mount your filesystem and chroot, https://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/chroot-to-repair-system

Comment: I did that the first time with the version you wrote, it seemed to work but I still cannot boot, same error. I tried the other versions because i saw them in ls, but even though the first version "works" i still cannot boot